# how to get values from database phpmyadmin and show

Tags: php, ajax

i need all values from database if i click button(get values) how can
i ? please assist me any one
 is there any way to do this ?

```
this is my index.php

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<form>
            <h1>Insert Data Into mySQL Database</h1>
            Name        <input name="name"      type="text" id="name"> <br><br>
            Lastname    <input name="lastname"  type="text" id="lastname"><br><br>
            Email       <input name="email"     type="text" id="email"><br><br>
            <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="insertData()">
</form>

<button type="button">get values</button>
<div id="jcontent"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* * Checking the Login - * */
            function insertData(){
                var data_get = {
                        'name_form': $('#name').val().trim(),
                        'lastname_form': $('#lastname').val().trim(),
                        'email_form': $('#email').val().trim()
                        };
                $.ajax({
                url     : 'insert_ac.php',
                type    : 'POST',
                data    : data_get,
                timeout : 30000,
                success : function(response_data, text, xhrobject) {
                        console.log(text);
                        if(text == "success"){
                            $('#jcontent').html('Data Inserted');
                        }
                        else if(text == "ERROR"){
                            $('#jcontent').html('data not inserted');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
/*******************************************************/
 this is my insert.php

 <?php



    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('loginthree');

    $table_name = "test_three";

    $name_form=$_POST['name_form'];
    $lastname_form=$_POST['lastname_form'];
    $email_form=$_POST['email_form'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO $table_name(name, lastname, email)VALUES('$name_form', '$lastname_form', '$email_form')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
    if($result){
        echo "Success";
    } else {
    echo "ERROR";
    }




?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

i need all values from database if i click button(get values) how can
i ? please assist me any one
 is there any way to do this ?

Comment: you know how to insert data in database.but don't know how to display data??

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us more about 1. your database structure and 2. what exactly you want to get since your get values button actually calls a INSERT statement on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly, insert a:

```
return false;
```

at the end of your insertData() function, in that way you prevent the refresh of the page so that the ajax call can load its data.

Second you are returning Success and you are trying to read success, it's case sensitive and your code will not reach that if.

Resolve these issues and get back to me

Answer (score 0):

Make a PHP script (lets name it getvalues.php) to return the values from the database into JSON, such as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $you_table"); //mod query to match what you need to fetch
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);   
echo json_encode($array);
```

Then in your script above include jQuery and use something along the lines of the following to retrieve the data:

```
$(function () 
  {
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'getvalues.php',         
      data: "",                        
      dataType: 'json',  
      success: function ( values )
      {
        var value1 = values[0]; //value1, value2, etc should represent the field names in your database
        var value2 = values[1];
        //and so on and so forth. each field in you DB should be one index in your values array
        $('#output').html("<b>Value 1: </b>"+value1+"<b> Value 2: </b>"+value2); 
      } 
    });
  });
```